# Button inside TextArea in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am looking to create a structure, in which a button is aligned to the top right of a textarea. I was able to do that using CSS positioning. When I start typing inside the textarea, the text comes below the button. Is there a way so that the text normally occupies the full width of the text area, but on reaching the bounds of the button, gets wrapped to the next line?

Comment: Semantically textarea should contain text only. Why do you want to place a button inside? Please explain with reasons.

Comment: I am trying to 'extend' some functionality of the textarea for mobile applications. With the button, I plan to add some functionality using JavaScript. Is it a bad approach?

Comment: Maybe a toolbar (a row of buttons) above the textarea would be better. I don't think the text in a textarea can flow around other controls.

Comment: could you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: You shouldn't try to place a button inside a textarea, that's doesn't make sense semantically and shouldn't be done. You could do what you're currently doing: positioning the button on top of the textarea in the right place. Using JavaScript you could probably add newlines to the textarea at the right spots, but I wonder whether that would be worth the effort.

Comment: Something similar to 
http://jsfiddle.net/8aAMa/7/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is always an option to use [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute on an inline element instead of `<textarea>` and put it next to a floating button.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button>press me</button>
    <span contenteditable="true">editable</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {border: 1px solid gray; width: 15em; height: 5em; overflow-y: scroll;}
button {float: right;}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aprillion/7KxDF/)

Comment: This works fine for me...Exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 8):

Fake it. Wrap the textarea and button in a containing div and position the elements. then style the container div to look like the text area. here's a rough mockup http://jsfiddle.net/LEkAJ/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <button>Button</button>
  <textarea>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</textarea>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
button {
    position:absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right:3px;
    width: 60px;
}
textarea {
    position:relative;
    border:none;
    width:232px;
    height: 95px;
    resize: none;
    outline: none; /* add this to stop highlight on focus */
}
```

Comment: Quite close to what I want, though it would be just right if I could flow the text around the button as well. If that is impossible, I would probably use this one

Comment: This doesn't actually put the button inside the textarea—just in the container. Adding a high z-index will show it above the text, but the text won't flow around it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Aprillion. This approach will work. Look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5pPRM/

html:

```
<p contenteditable="true">
<button onclick="alert($(this).parent().find('span').text());">hello</button>
    <span>
This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text. This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.
    </span>
</p>
```

css

```
p
{
position:relative;
}
button
{
position:relative;
float:right;
margin: 0 0 2% 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice implementation of what I want to do. Only glitch is that if I remove all the text, I can edit the text inside the button. Still nice implementation

Comment: I updated my own answer to address the deletable button.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the solution below, it repositions the button every time you resize the Textarea

```js
// define the heights
var tH = $('textarea').height();
var bH = $('.btn').height();

// last height before resize
var lastHeight = $("textarea").css('height');
//tracker like an event listener
function check() {
  if ($('textarea').css('height') != lastHeight) {
    lastHeight = $('textarea').css('height')
    r(lastHeight)
  }

  setTimeout(check, 1);
}
// re-position the button vertically
function r(x) {
  let pos = (parseInt(x) - (parseInt(bH)*3));
  let border = 1;
  let padding = 10;
  pos += (border??1) + (padding??0); 
  let h =  pos + "px";

  document.querySelector('.btn').style.top = h;
}
// run script
r(lastHeight)
check()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.container textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100% !important;
  resize: vertical;
}

.container .btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <textarea rows="12"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="btn"> Save </button>
</div>
```

## **EDIT**

I can't stop myself laughing at my IQ level, instead of using `top` and calculate it in JS, I can use `bottom`  in CSS

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.container{
  position: relative;
}
.container textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100% !important;
  resize: vertical;
}

.container .btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px; /* <==== */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea rows="12"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="btn"> Save </button>
</div>
```