# How to put a floated button inside a textarea?

Tags: html, css, forms, css-float, textarea

I need to make this:[image: Textarea with a button inside]

Using Vue framework and postcss preprocessor.

I was trying a variant with contenteditable span which found here - [Button inside TextArea in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951507/button-inside-textarea-in-html) however button isn't floated, text just hides under the button like it has an absolute positioning:

```
<div class="feedback__textarea">
  <app-btn theme="deepwater" class="feedback__btn">Отправить</app-btn>
  <span contenteditable="true"
        class="feedback__input"
        id="feedback-form-message"
        name="message"></span>
</div>

.feedback__textarea {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: var(--white);
}

.feedback__textarea .feedback__input {
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    color: var(--dark-grey);
    word-break: break-all;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
}

.feedback__btn {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably expecting this:

https://codebrace.com/editor/b09138c60

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//codebrace.com/embed/b09138c60/?12px&amp;wordwrap&amp;html&amp;css&amp;xcode&amp;focus=css" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" style="background-color:transparent; overflow: hidden;margin: 0;" title="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

So I have placed the text area in div container with `position: relative` with the "feedback__btn" as `position: absolute` positioned at bottom right corner.

**Updated solution:**
https://codebrace.com/editor/b0b504fb2

Adding margin-bottom to textarea will keep button from hiding textarea. I have updated the solution for your reference. I hope this solves your problem :).

Comment: I need an input floating around the button. In my and yours variants it hides under the button.

Comment: I see my answer isn't clear enough, I need an input to be able to appear on the same height with the button so that you have like a textarea without only bottom right corner. In your new variant it's without the whole bottom line.

Comment: I have updated the solution with multiline textarea https://codebrace.com/editor/b0bc013d8

Comment: thanks for help, I think this problem is really hard one. Your new solution has one minus that text is only appear on the left side of the button, I need a text to be able to float it not only from one side but from two - top and left.

Comment: Hmmm...  Do you mean the text inside the button to appear on the top left side? It would be helpful, If you could produce a screenshot of your requirement.